# Rewriting this equation without the square roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Given the following system of equations:

$\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}+s(t_2-t_1) = \sqrt{(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2}$

$\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}+s(t_3-t_2) = \sqrt{(x-x_3)^2 + (y-y_3)^2}$

$\sqrt{(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2}+s(t_3-t_1) = \sqrt{(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2}$

How could I write this *without* square roots? Here, the goal is to solve the system to determine the unknowns $x$ and $y$. How do I solve this (the goal is to do so algorithmically)?

Comment: It's hyperbola.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Hi. Yes, this is a hyperbola. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what that means for solving the system (it is a system of 3 equations with 2 unknowns). I know it's "elementary", however it's been so long I don't remember.

Comment: It means to write it in the form $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=\pm1.$

Comment: It is one of *two* hyperbolas

Comment: shouldn't the last equation have $x_3,y_3,...,x_1,y_1$ ???

Comment: @Physor I think you're right, however two sources I'm using disagree on this... I'll edit it to be this in the meantime, as I believe that's correct.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly helpful. I guess I'm not sure how to go from that to obtaining $x$ and $y$, however. Again, it's probably something stupid simple, but it's been a while and for some reason I'm having the hardest time wrapping my head around this.

Comment: @Physor Yep. $t$ refers to time, and $x$, $y$ to coordinates in space, of course. And yes, this is 2-dimensional.

Comment: could please consider accepting the answer, if it is still usefull, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sqrt{a^2}+b = \sqrt{c^2} \\
\implies a^2 + b^2 + 2b\sqrt{a^2} = c^2 \\
\implies a^2 + b^2 + 2b(\sqrt{c^2}-b) = c^2 \\
\implies \sqrt{c^2} = \frac{c^2 -a^2 - b^2}{2b} + b \\
\implies c^2 = \left(\frac{c^2 -a^2 - b^2}{2b} + b \right)^2
$$
$$
\iff c = \pm \left(\frac{c^2 -a^2 - b^2}{2b} + b \right)
$$

Comment: Why was the fourth step neccesary? You could have written the fourth step right after the fifth step right after the third :P

Comment: @Buraian I had to isolate the square root on one side to square it and get rid of it. This is because the qusetion was about rewriting the eqaution without square roots